файлы png ,Jpg, svg добавленные инлайн в WordPress не воспроизводятся Chrome, FireFox
Графические (*.png. *.jpg) файлы и файлы *.svg добавленные инлайн (скопированные) в html код страниц  WordPress не воспроизводятся в Chrome, FireFox.
Также не решается проблема при попытке добавления внешних файлов с помощью <object> или других способов  добавления внешних файлов *.svg.


a{
    display: inline-block;
}
object{
    pointer-events: none;
}
<a href="https://www.google.ru" target="_blank">
    <object data="http://images3.wikia.nocookie.net/__cb20120330024139/logopedia/images/d/d7/Google_Chrome_logo_2011.svg" type="image/svg+xml">
        <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/8/87/Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).png" style="
    width: 250px;"/>
    </object> 
</a>



код svg - Google_Chrome_icon_(2011).png


<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<svg
   xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/"
   xmlns:cc="http://creativecommons.org/ns#"
   xmlns:rdf="http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#"
   xmlns:svg="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg"
   xmlns:sodipodi="http://sodipodi.sourceforge.net/DTD/sodipodi-0.dtd"
   xmlns:inkscape="http://www.inkscape.org/namespaces/inkscape"
   viewBox="0 0 256 256"
   id="svg2"
   version="1.1"
   inkscape:version="0.48.1 r9760"
   width="256"
   height="256"
   sodipodi:docname="Google_Chrome_2011_Logo SVG.svg">
  <metadata
     id="metadata69">
    <rdf:RDF>
      <cc:Work
         rdf:about="">
        <dc:format>image/svg+xml</dc:format>
        <dc:type
           rdf:resource="http://purl.org/dc/dcmitype/StillImage" />
        <dc:title></dc:title>
      </cc:Work>
    </rdf:RDF>
  </metadata>
  <sodipodi:namedview
     pagecolor="#ffffff"
     bordercolor="#666666"
     borderopacity="1"
     objecttolerance="10"
     gridtolerance="10"
     guidetolerance="10"
     inkscape:pageopacity="0"
     inkscape:pageshadow="2"
     inkscape:window-width="640"
     inkscape:window-height="480"
     id="namedview67"
     showgrid="false"
     inkscape:zoom="1.140625"
     inkscape:cx="128"
     inkscape:cy="128"
     inkscape:window-x="0"
     inkscape:window-y="0"
     inkscape:window-maximized="0"
     inkscape:current-layer="svg2" />
  <defs
     id="defs4">
    <linearGradient
       id="blueFade"
       x1="0%"
       y1="0%"
       x2="0%"
       y2="100%">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="#81b4e0"
         id="stop7" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="#0c5a94"
         id="stop9" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="redFade"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="128"
       y1="16"
       x2="128"
       y2="107">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="#f06b59"
         id="stop12" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="#df2227"
         id="stop14" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="greenFade"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="72"
       y1="225"
       x2="118"
       y2="149">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="#388b41"
         id="stop17" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="#4cb749"
         id="stop19" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="yellowFade"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="187"
       y1="220"
       x2="138"
       y2="102">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="#e4b022"
         id="stop22" />
      <stop
         offset="30%"
         stop-color="#fcd209"
         id="stop24" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="redShadow"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="80"
       y1="140"
       x2="80"
       y2="60">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".15"
         id="stop27" />
      <stop
         offset="30%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".06"
         id="stop29" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".03"
         id="stop31" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="greenShadow"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="164"
       y1="161"
       x2="109"
       y2="217">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".15"
         id="stop34" />
      <stop
         offset="30%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".06"
         id="stop36" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".03"
         id="stop38" />
    </linearGradient>
    <linearGradient
       id="yellowShadow"
       gradientUnits="userSpaceOnUse"
       x1="139"
       y1="179"
       x2="147"
       y2="100">
      <stop
         offset="0%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".15"
         id="stop41" />
      <stop
         offset="30%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".06"
         id="stop43" />
      <stop
         offset="100%"
         stop-color="black"
         stop-opacity=".03"
         id="stop45" />
    </linearGradient>
  </defs>
  <circle
     cx="128"
     cy="128"
     r="110"
     fill="white"
     id="circle47" />
  <path
     fill="black"
     fill-opacity=".1"
     d="M 198 148 A 70 70 0 0 0 58 148 L 78 148 A 50 50 0 0 1 178 148"
     id="path49" />
  <circle
     fill="black"
     fill-opacity=".1"
     cx="133"
     cy="142"
     r="38"
     id="circle51" />
  <circle
     cx="50%"
     cy="50%"
     r="41"
     fill="url(#blueFade)"
     id="circle53" />
  <path
     fill="url(#redFade)"
     d="M 228 78 A 112 112 0 0 0 35 65 L 80 143 A 50 50 0 0 1 127 78"
     id="path55" />
  <path
     fill="url(#greenFade)"
     d="M 35 65 A 112 112 0 0 0 119 239 L 166 159 A 50 50 0 0 1 80 143"
     id="path57" />
  <path
     fill="url(#yellowFade)"
     d="M 119 239 A 112 112 0 0 0 228 78 L 127 78 A 50 50 0 0 1 166 159"
     id="path59" />
  <path
     fill="url(#redShadow)"
     d="M 35 65 L 80 143 A 50 50 0 0 1 82 109 L 37 62"
     id="path61" />
  <path
     fill="url(#greenShadow)"
     d="M 119 239 L 166 159 A 50 50 0 0 1 137 176 L 117 239"
     id="path63" />
  <path
     fill="url(#yellowShadow)"
     d="M 228 78 L 127 78 A 50 50 0 0 1 166 97 L 230 81"
     id="path65" />
</svg>



Встроенный инлайн файл в wordPress либо молча не воспроизводится, либо выдает сообщение об ошибке формат файла не поддерживается и MIME-тип не найден при попытке добавления внешнего файла с помощью различных способов: <object>, <iframe>, <img>, <embed> приводит к тому же результату, вернее к  полному отсутствию появления изображения svg/png/jpg
Что нужно изменить в настройках wordPress, чтобы решить проблему воспроизведения файлов во всех браузерах?

Что в данном случае подразумевается под "не воспроизводятся"? И куда и посредством чего эти файлы туда добавляются? В том числе и встраивание кодом.

@Simon прочитайте пожалуйста внимательно ещё раз вопрос. Там, на мой взгляд все подробно и доходчиво объяснено.

Если под воспроизведением подразумевается отображение, то причин может быть уйма, данные вводные фактически ничего не дают. Начать вероятно стоит с тривиального Дебаг в WordPress. Так же, наверное имело бы смысл указать КУДА именно Вы добавляете <object>, <iframe>, <img>, <embed>, так как в некоторых случаях данные теги и их атрибуты могут быть просто обрезаны/вырезаны.

@Simon причина и решение тривиальны. В вопросе четко сказано, что внешние файлы встраивались онлайн в html код страничек wordPress  с помощью <object> либо код просто копировался в html страничек wordPress Мало того с этой проблемой я столкнулся при создании своего реального сайта. Вам что-то ещё нужно пояснить?

@Leonid очепятка - инлайн имелось ввиду

Так какой ответ приходит от сервера? Что там в коде? (Ctrl + U, F12) Что там вместо ссылок на файлы? Что во вкладке Network?

@Alexandr_TT Я добавил приведенный Вами код на сайт развернутый у меня локально в Docker и все прекрасно работает. Каким образом из вопроса я должен был понять как Вы его встроили? Можно встроить это в PHP шаблон напрямую, можно встроить в WYSIWYG редактор Classic Editor перейдя в вкладку "Text", Вы можете это встроить как Custom HTML в Gutenberg, через ACF/PODs/Carbon Fields и еще ряд подобных плагинов, изображение у Вас может быть как загружено через медиатеку WordPress так и быть просто изображением с стороннего ресурса, WordPress так же по-умолчанию не поддерживает SVG и тд и тп.

Если причина и решение тривиальны, к чему этот вопрос здесь?

Как правильно задать вопрос по WordPress?

@Simon Если причина и решение тривиальны, к чему этот вопрос здесь? Этот вопрос новички задают много-много раз. Ответ в сообщении об ошибке, который есть в вопросе. Это вопрос в стиле вопрос с самоответом. Ответ я не публикую сразу, чтобы люди попытались порешать сами. Когда ответ уже есть, люди проходят мимо и ещё и обижаются, типо только хотел ответить, а ответ уже появился :)

Ну то есть, у Вас был неверно сконфигурирован сервер, я верно понял?

@Simon С сервером все было в порядке, как и сейчас в порядке. Сервер  штатный, находится у хостера.

@Simon проблемы были на клиентской стороне, а именно неправильная конфигурация файла ** .htaccess**


Как правило сообщение об ошибке,-  формат файла не поддерживается и MIME-типе не найдено.

Хочу дать более расширенный ответ, на случай возникновения подобных вопросов:

Не запускается на просмотр файлы с расширением *.svg
Не работает svg код добавленный внутрь html страниц
Не работает svg код добавленный внутрь  страниц WordPress
Не открываются файлы с расширением *.xml
Не открываются графические файлы *.jpg, *.png и другие растровые файлы

Решение для WordPress:
По умолчанию WordPress не поддерживает файлы *.svg, *.svgz.
Поэтому выпущено множество плагинов, решающих эту проблему.
Для WordPress можно установить плагин, который всё сделает за вас.
Если плагин не помог или не хочется использовать плагины, то можно добавить MIME type в ручную:
Указание MIME-типа image/svg+xml необходимо в HTML при передаче данных с помощью файлов *.svg и вставки на страницу различных объектов SVG.
1. Добавляете в файл functions.php
Откройте ваш functions.php и добавьте следующий код:
function wpcontent_svg_mime_type( $mimes = array() ) {
      $mimes['svg']  = 'image/svg+xml';
      $mimes['svgz'] = 'image/svg+xml';
      return $mimes;
    }
    add_filter( 'upload_mimes', 'wpcontent_svg_mime_type' ); 

Вы должны заменить wpcontent_ своим собственным пространством имен. Эта функция просто добавляет SVG и SVGZ (сжатый SVG) к разрешенным типам загружаемых файлов в WordPress и подключается к функции WordPress upload_mimes().
2. Добавление SVG Mime Types в .htaccess
Откройте ваш корневой файл .htaccess и добавьте следующее после строки: #End WordPress.
# Add SVG Mime Types
AddType image/svg+xml svg
AddType image/svg+xml svgz        

Сохраните файл, и все готово! Теперь вы можете сохранять SVG из Illustrator или Inkscape и использовать их на своем сайте WordPress.
Файл .htaccess обычно расположен в корне диска “C:”
Если на вашем ПК его нет, то можно его создать самому:
Вот содержание этого файла по умолчанию:
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>
 
# END WordPress

